# Possível leitura dos dados no firebase

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, firebase

Boa tarde 
 Queria tirar uma duvida em relação a Firebase Realtime Database.
 Tenho alguns dados armazenados no meu firebase mas queria fazer uma consunta ou leitura deles através de uma pagina HTML é possível e como fazer

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write